# Play framework evolution script error line number

Tags: sql-server, playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

I'm using *evolution scripts*, via *Slick*, using the *Play Framework* to update the schema for a *Microsoft SQL Server database*.

This largely works great, except that when something goes wrong, I just get a terse error message, with no indication which line of the script caused the error, and—for large scripts—that makes identifying the error time-consuming and challenging.

For example, consider this error:

```
An evolution has not been applied properly. Please check the problem and resolve it manually before marking it as resolved. -
We got the following error: , while trying to run this SQL script:
```

That's it.

Is there a way to get the full error message (through a log file, a configuration setting, etc.) that includes the line number and context, etc. with the evolution failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but I finally figured this out.

I edited the `conf/logback.xml` file to include the following:

```xml
  <logger name="play.api.db.evolutions" level="DEBUG" />
```

Each statement in the *Ups* script is then written to `logs/application.log` as it is executed, together with its result, including detailed error messages.